# How do I update scripts from OpenMx 1 to OpenMx 2?

Tags: r, structural-equation-model, openmx

I have an example [OpenMx](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/OpenMx/index.html) script written a few years ago to do twin modelling.

It was written for OpenMx version 1.0 (script [linked here](http://openmx.psyc.virginia.edu/thread/4100) )

When I run it, there are some warnings about updating fit functions and objectives. How should I update it to use OpenMx 2.0 fit function calls?

Answer (score 2):

There are a small number of changes from OpenMx 1.0 to 2.0 and higher. Nearly all scripts will run fine, but some pre-2012 or will benefit in features if you update for OpenMx 2.x

An example is [referenced](http://openmx.psyc.virginia.edu/thread/4100) here

The user had hassles with:

#### 1. No path to the helper functions

This is a more generic robustness issue for example R code: better to include web urls rather than disk-based file paths.

```
source("http://www.vipbg.vcu.edu/~vipbg/Tc24/GenEpiHelperFunctions.R")
```

A better solution is CRAN-based helper packages like *[umx](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/umx/index.html)*. These are easier to keep up to date and accessible.

#### 2. Old-style objectives (instead of expectations and fit functions)

Calls like this one are deprecated:

```
objMZ<- mxFIMLObjective(covariance="expCovMZ", means="expMean", dimnames=selVars)
```

It’s easy to update these across a stack of scripts, replacing `mxFIMLObjective` with `mxExpectationNormal` + a call to `mxFitFunctionML`

In addition, in old-style multiple-group objectives like this:

```
minus2ll <- mxAlgebra( expression = MZ.objective + DZ.objective, name="m2LL")
obj  <- mxAlgebraObjective("m2LL")
```

You should replace `mxAlgebraObjective` with `mxFitFunctionAlgebra`

**However**, OpenMx 2 has a neat Multigroup function which handles this in one line and enables identification checks, reference model generation etc.

So just replace the whole thing with (for example):

```
mxFitFunctionMultigroup(c("MZ", "DZ"))}
```